# Python: Ensuring my class gets pickled only with the latest protocol

Tags: python, pickle

I'm developing a class which can be meaningfully pickled only using protocol 2 (and upwards on Python 3.) When an older protocol is used, hard-to-trace bugs happen. I want to save the users of the class some debugging pain, so I want the class to immediately raise an exception if it's being pickled with a protocol of less than 2.

How can I do that?

Comment: """ can be meaningfully pickled only using protocol 2.""" - why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement the [`__reduce_ex__()`](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html#object.__reduce_ex__) method on your class.  It receives one parameter, which is the protocol version.  Simply raise an exception if the version is not 2.

Comment: Interesting. Do you think it will interfere with the operation of `__getnewargs__` which I'm using?

Comment: Seems like it doesn't interfere.