# Traversing object hierarchy pickle style

Tags: python, django, serialization, pickle, celery

I'm in a need for doing some sort of processing on the objects that get pickled just before it happens. More precisely for instances of subclasses of a certain base class I would like something totally different to be pickled instead and then recreated on loading.

I'm aware of `__getstate__` & `__setstate__` however this is a very invasive approach. My understanding is that these are private methods (begin with double underscore: `__`), and as such are subject to name mangling. Therefore this effectively would force me to redefine those two methods for every single class that I want to be subject to this non standard behavior. In addition I don't really have a full control over the hierarchy of all classes.

I was wondering if there is some sort of brief way of hooking into pickling process and applying this sort of control that `__getstate__` and `__setstate__` give but without having to modify the pickled classes as such.

A side note for the curious ones. This is a use case taken from a project using Django and Celery. Django models are either unpickable or very unpractical and cumbersome to pickle. Therefore it's much more advisable to pickle pairs of values ID + model class instead. However sometimes it's not the model directly that is pickled but rather a dictionary of models, a list of models, a list of lists of models, you name it. This forces me to write a lot of copy-paste code that I really dislike. A need for pickling models comes itself from Django-celery setup, where functions along with their call arguments are scheduled for later execution. Unfortunately among those arguments there are usually a lot of models mixed up in some nontrivial hierarchy.

**EDIT**

I do have a possibility of specifying a custom serializer to be used by Celery, so it's really a question of being able to build a slightly modified serializer on top of pickle without much effort.

Answer (score 2):

The only additional hooks that are related are **reduce**() and __reduce__ex()

http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html

[What is the difference between __reduce__ and __reduce_ex__?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150284/what-is-the-difference-between-reduce-and-reduce-ex)

[Python: Ensuring my class gets pickled only with the latest protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5570680/python-ensuring-my-class-gets-pickled-only-with-the-latest-protocol)

Not sure if they really provide what you need in particular.

Comment: But this again requires me to implement some additional methods on the class whose instances are pickled. So it's again an invasive approach, or do I misunderstand?

Comment: Then you have no other options on the pickle level ...case closed

Comment: well you could create a class hierarchy and make a base class have these additional methods and everything would descend from this base class instead of object?